# How to rustup update when permission is denied?

Tags: rust, rustup

When I ran `rustup update`, I got the following error:

```
info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
error: could not create temp file /home/abc/.rustup/tmp/mbbafo7rtfs5aazi_file
info: checking for self-updates

  stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu update failed - rustc 1.52.1 (9bc8c42bb 2021-05-09)

info: cleaning up downloads & tmp directories
thread 'main' panicked at 'Unable to clean up /home/abc/.rustup/downloads: Os { code: 13, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Permission denied" }', src/utils/utils.rs:642:13
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Then, I tried to run `sudo rustup update` and got the following:

```
sudo: rustup: command not found
```

The output of `ls -l /home/abc/.rustup/` is:

```
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 31 14:06 downloads
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  102 May 31 14:06 settings.toml
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 31 14:06 tmp
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 31 14:06 toolchains
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 31 14:06 update-hashes
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -l /home/abc/.rustup`?

Comment: I edited the question to include the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you installed the Rust toolchain using the `root` account. This can be fixed by changing the user and group permissions of `.rustup`.

```
sudo chown -R abc:abc /home/abc/.rustup
rustup update
```

If your `/home/abc/.cargo` is also owned by `root` you will probably want to fix that too.